# Chris Pine Learn to Program Ruby Ch 9: Psych Test program

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

So I'm following along and doing the Psych Test [burrito, taco, wets_bed] program in Chris Pine... yes, I changed to the lyrics of "Escape: The Pina Colada song" but otherwise, kept the same.

However, it's getting stuck on the first 'ask' . . . help?

I don't want to change this drastically, just trying to find where the program is getting hung.

```
# Nice little questionnaire 

def ask question
  good_answer = false
  while (not good_answer)
    puts question
    reply = gets.chomp.downcase

    if (reply == 'yes' or reply == 'no' )
      good_answer == true
      if reply == 'yes'
        answer = true
      else
        answer = false
      end
    else 
      puts 'Please answer "yes" or "no".'
    end
  end

  answer # This is what we return (true or false)
end

puts 'Hello, and thank you for smoking.'

puts

ask 'Do you like pina-coladas?'
ask 'Do you like getting caught in the rain?'
risky_business = ask 'Do you know what your sig other likes?'
ask 'Are you into yoga?'
ask 'Do you have half a brain?'
puts 'Just a few more questions.'
ask 'Do like the feel of the ocean?'
ask 'Are you into champagne?'

puts
puts 'DEBRIEFING'
puts 'Thank\'s for all the fish'
puts
puts risky_business
```

That's it. 
I'm wondering if this could be a Ruby version issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

is this line a problem? `good_answer == true`

shouldn't it be `good_answer = true`

Comment: AH! Thank you... I had a feeling it was something like that.

Answer (score 1):

If you had warnings turned on, Ruby itself would tell you about the `good_answer == true` line not making sense.

You can turn warnings on with `$VERBOSE  = true` within your code, or by having the unix variable `RUBYOPT` include `-w` .

Answer (score 0):

BTW, I would rewrite the ask function like so to make more in line with the Ruby way:

```
def ask(question)
  puts question

  while reply = gets.chomp.downcase
    if %w( yes no ).include?(reply)
      answer = if reply == 'yes' then true else false end
      break
    else
      puts 'Please answer "yes" or "no".'
    end
  end

  answer
end
```

Comment: That is good to know, but it's way beyond what's going on in this section of Chris Pine's book.